# Does LambdaExpression.Compile() create an extra assembly which is dynamically loaded?

Tags: .net, expression, clr

I want to have several routines which are dynamically created using Expression trees. It seems that the easiest way to use them would be to create `LambdaExpression` and then call `LambdaExpression`.
`Compile()` resulting in a callable delegate.

1. What are the possible performance penalties of such solution?
2. What exactly happens during the compilation?
3. Is an extra assembly with an extra new class type created and dynamically loaded?
4. Does it happen everytime I call the `Compile()`?
5. Is it better to create a new type and include all the routines as static methods of this type by using `TypeBuilder` and `MethodBuilder`?

Any suggestions are welcome!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. the emit stage, reflection-initiated delegate creation - and indeed simply building the expression tree - is relatively expensive; if you do that *every time* it will hurt; if, however, you cache the strategies effectively (so you're not building the expression tree and compiling it constantly), it is perfectly fine and *a reasonable way of doing meta-programming*
2. typically, a [`DynamicMethod`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.reflection.emit.dynamicmethod) is generated - which is a standalone method that avoids all the usual weight of `AssemblyBuiler`, `ModuleBuilder`, `TypeBuilder` etc, and *just* provides raw access to an `ILGenerator` to a `static`-style method; the code then walks the expression tree, emitting the appropriate op-codes via `ILGenerator`; finally, [`CreateDelegate`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.reflection.emit.dynamicmethod.createdelegate) is called on the `DynamicMethod`
3. no; `DynamicMethod` tries to avoid this
4. yes; so try to cache your strategies
5. depends on context; there are things `DynamicMethod` can do that `TypeBuilder` can't (accessibility skipping, for example), and there are things that `TypeBuilder` can do that `DynamicMethod` can't (implement interfaces, declare and use fields, etc); if you don't need those things, `Expression.Compile()` is a pretty good way of avoiding having to learn low-level ref-emit, which is *very easy to get wrong* (and invalid IL usually kills the runtime)
6. (you didn't ask a 6, but...) it should also be noted that `Expression` can choose to *spoof* the emit, by actually running via an AST interpreter instead, on runtimes that do not allow ref-emit; `Compile()` returns an entry-point to this interpreter, *instead of* a delegate to a dynamically compiled method; this option is not available if you use `TypeBuilder`

Comment: Thanks a lot for the super useful information. I seem to have to get more familiar with the DynamicMethod.. Is it possible to say the LambdaExpression.Compile(preferInterpretation: true) will be *always* interpreted in case the system supports both, interpretation and compilation?

Comment: @Rexxowski it *looks* like the code [checks for a feature-flag](https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/blob/c22714d65151968a17c3b232748880d5e7961dee/src/System.Linq.Expressions/src/System/Linq/Expressions/LambdaExpression.cs#L123), but it also looks like that feature flag is [always enabled](https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/blob/c22714d65151968a17c3b232748880d5e7961dee/src/System.Linq.Expressions/src/System.Linq.Expressions.csproj#L3); make of that what you will